# android.utils.Base64.encode gets different value

Tags: android, base64, encode

When I try this:

```
map.put("password1", Base64.encode("111111".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
map.put("password2", Base64.encode("111111".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
map.put("password3", Base64.encode("111111".getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT));
```

I got different value of password1,password2 and password3:

**password1**:**[B@5368aecc**

**password2**:**[B@536e9ea0**

**password3**:**[B@536c0dec**

Is it should be the same value?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I should use "Base64.encodeToString" instead of "Base64.encode"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're essentially printing `toString()` of a `byte[]` array. The output is different for different byte array objects.

Either don't store the values as byte arrays by removing the `.getBytes()`, or convert your byte arrays back to string with `new String(byteArray, someEncoding)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its can be same , when u add a some text to your string, the old part of string is in hashed string same. Check more at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding)